# Building magento modules

Tags: php, magento, module

I'm just about to start building my first magento module but I can't find any literature on the difference between the local and community folder in core.  I've noticed that some people build their modules in local and others in community, what is the difference and why should I use one or the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to develop out of local.  The community folder is/was intended to be the place where you'd put modules that you downloaded or bought from the Magento Marketplace.  It's my understanding that the use of this folder is being phased out, and it's Varian's recommendation that all modules be placed in the local folder, even those downloaded from the marketplace.

From a system point of view, the only difference is the community folder is searched after the core folder, but before the local folder.  Checkout this path setup in app/Mage.php

```
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

$app_path = implode(PS, $paths);

set_include_path($app_path . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
```

So, if you have two files

```
app/code/community/Companyname/Models/Foo.php
app/code/local/Companyname/Models/Foo.php
```

Magento will use the one in the community folder first.

Comment: Ignore what I said above about community being phased out.  Local is for things you're doing locally to your store, community is **supposed** to be for modules being distributed.  When you distribute your module in the community folder you allow someone to override a class, code-pool style, in local.  However, because there hasn't been clear communication on this, lots of distributed modules end up in community.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `community`, if your module is planned to be distributed to the public, to allow other Magento developers to use your module in their own Magento projects, too.

That's what Varien calls a [Magento Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect).

You should use `local` instead, if you do not want to distribute to the public, but are developing the module mainly for a specific shop (or maybe your personal use) only.

To better understand the difference between the `local` and the `community` folder, it helps to know how the Magento Autoloader works:

When a `class` is about to be instantiated in Magento, the Autoloader will search for matching classes in the order given by PHPs [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Magento initially sets its `include_path` in `app/Mage.php` upon start:

```
:

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

Mage::register('original_include_path', get_include_path());

:

$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

$app_path = implode(PS, $paths);
set_include_path($app_path . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));

:
```

The Magento Autoloader searches paths in the **same** order they appear in `include_path`:

```
1st /app/code/local/
2nd /app/code/community/
3rd /app/code/core/
4th /lib/
:
```

Assuming you are trying to instantiate a class named `Namespace_Module_Block_Hello` for example, that would result in having Magentos Autoloader searching the paths given by `include_path` for a file named `Namespace/Module/Block/Hello.php`*:

```
1st /app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Hello.php
2nd /app/code/community/Namespace/Module/Block/Hello.php
3rd /app/code/core/Namespace/Module/Block/Hello.php
4th /lib/Namespace/Module/Block/Hello.php
:
```

The **first** file found will win, i.e. get instantiated. So if the same file exists in `local` AND `community` for example, the `local` one would be instantiated.

This allows developers to freely extend/override/overload/ignore classes.

---

*<sub>see `lib/Varien/Autoload.php::autoload()` for name conversion rules</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The local folder is for modules that only you will use. The community folder is for modules that will eventually be packaged and made available (or sold) to the magento community. Any modules you download and install are placed in the community folder. Magento doesn't really care where your module is, the distinction is there mainly to keep modules organized. In any case since it's easy to switch from one to another it shouldn't really bother you all that much.

If you don't know which category your module belongs in, you can start in the local folder and if it is to be published, you can move it to the community folder later.

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of categorization for the module.

1. Community and commercial 
   Community - free for the community
   Commercial - paid for the community
2. Local and Core
   Core - Extension is developed using magento core files.
   Local - Extension is developed by copying core files to the local. Actual changes are done at the local

Local one is more advisable...